# Comparing values with some alphanumerics

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've looked through the forums but couldn't find any questions (with answers) that helped.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

I'm working on an Excel/Access project that cross references error codes.  The codes are twelve digits long, with the first half and second half that need to be sortable.  99% of these codes are entirely numeric, but the 1% that includes letters is really screwing me up.

For example, a common error code might be "386748000123".  This would be split into "386748" and "000123", with the first being the code for the type of system and the second being the type of error.

But then the 1% are something like this: "0957AB003A41".  "0957AB", and "003A41".

If I format the columns (in Excel and Access) as numbers than the numeric comparisons are far easier, "000123" equals "123".  If I format the column as strings than I can compare the alphanumeric values but then "000123" and "123" stop crossing.

The possible solution I've come across is utilizing the Val function inside an Access query to purely compare values but I've never used it and it seems like only a partial fix.  Val ignores the strings, which means "0957AB" will have the same value as "0957XY" - and that doesn't work for this project.

I'm sure many of you have had similar issues, so I'm hoping to get some ideas on different ways the problem has been approached and resolved.

Comment: Have you tried vbBinaryCompare comparisons using InStr(), or Left() and Right()?

Comment: This is not difficult, you can have many approaches, I would keep them strings all the time, and just format it so if you format 123 as a 6 character it would be 000123 and anything coming from Access can be compared easily so use `format(123,"000000")`

Comment: That's correct if I have the columns formatted for strings, the zeroes cause problems depending on where they are placed.  My "main" table with the error codes is cross referenced with the "key" that describes the fault.  So I download the codes, split them in half, then compare the halves against the key.  My table will show something like "001234" and the key will only show "1234"... with length depending on the number of zeroes.  It could be "000001" vs "1".  I've been keeping everything formatted as numbers for the time being to avoid problems with those zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a minimal sample of the data and also the output, also there is no code that I can amend it for you, but the only part that you are having problem is comparing the alphanumeric ones, you should format all of your data as strings and then compare. to make 123 be equal to "000123" you need to just format the numeric ones as string as below:

```
format(123,"000000")
```

which will give you `"000123"`

**Edit**

from you comment I learned that the problem is the key that is always or often a number, `format` will return the proper string for comparison, if it is already a 6-character string it will return itself so there would not be a problem:

do something like this:

```
if format(key,"0000000")=format(code,"000000") then
    'do something
end if
```